# Sending lists between pages Flask/Python

Tags: python, flask

I'm fairly new to Flask and I'm creating an app that makes queries on a database.

The db is pretty big and I want to make the query which includes filters, and put it into a python list on one page and then send the Python list results to another page and make queries on the Python list instead of on the database which is slow and contains lots of irrelevant data.

I've tried to share it using Flask Session but the list is too big to send across so I'm wondering if anyone has any solutions to send the data across.

```
@app.route("/")
def simple():
    # MAKE THE QUERY ON THIS PAGE FROM SQL to Python List (Transfer List to '/menu')
    return render_template("my-form.html")

@app.route('/menu', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def load_data():
    # MAKE A QUERY ON THE LIST FROM "/" ON THIS PAGE
    return render_template("my-form.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Never do in code what you can get the SQL server to do well for you.

It's not recommended that take a lot of data from the database and handle it,I suggest you **do your best to filter the data in the database**.Sometimes big data will take a lot of bandwidth, and if you want to handle it in Python,it might take a lot of memory.

If you want to return large data to the web page,maybe you can split up the data and render them to serveral pages,this will simplify your problem,on the other hand,you can try to use `LIMIT` clause,it might reduce the pressure on the network and memory.

Maybe [Streaming Contents](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/streaming/#streaming-from-templates) is also a good way to solve your problem when you want to send an enormous amount of data.

By the way,in my opnion,if the database is pretty large, at first, you should optimize your indexes in the tables,this will make your SQL query faster.Also it's a good idea for you to use the suitable storage engine which offers very high table compression on reading data,like `MyISAM`.

Hope this helps.